# Webscraping the html from a page but I need the cookies

Tags: python, web-scraping, cookies, python-requests

I've been trying to webscrape (I'm an amateur) this site for a while: "https://www.coches.net/segunda-mano/", but I haven't been able to do so and I have a few ideas on how to solve it but none have worked.

I noticed that this part of the site doesn't have antiscraping protection"https://www.coches.net/km-0/" so I tried to get the cookies for headers request from there but it didn't work.

I read the javascript that I believe generates the cookies but I have 0 idea about java script and the code is just a mess ("https://www.coches.net/ztkieflaaxcvaiwh2").

And lastly what I did was purchase a free trial of octoparse that can scrape the html and then I request with python that data using octoparse API, but I can't use this much longer because storing data/scripts in their servers requires you to have a premium suscription which I'm not able to pay every month for the little projects that I do, so, I just wanted to know if there is a way to simulate what octoparse does in python or to generate the cookies required for my request headers to go through.

I also had a look at the cookies  and I found that every time I get blocked for doing too many requests I only have to do a CAPTCHA manually and the site resets and gives me new cookies, and this is the structure of the cookies:

```
_hjid= stays the same
borosTcf= stays the same
ajs_anonymous_id= stays the same
_pbjs_userid_consent_data= stays the same
_gcl_au= stays the same
__gads= stays the same
gig_bootstrap_3_ejKPtiTCoMZOmiD2PJgl0GYbIQOdeBma77joBheqTs15Nx5EkD9evJSOuefj2S6H= stays the same
euconsent-v2= stays the same
cfg= stays the same
_hjSession_48459= stays the same
_hjIncludedInSessionSample= stays the same
_hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress= stays the same
AMCVS_05FF6243578784B37F000101@AdobeOrg= stays the same
AMCV_05FF6243578784B37F000101@AdobeOrg= stays the same
reese84=3: This one is different each time
cto_bundle= This one is different each time
```

I appreciate any help, this is driving me nuts, the other sites that I ever scraped just needed a simple headers structure o a simple data payload, but I'm new to this so at some point I had to ask for help.

Comment: The reese84 cookie denotes that the site is using advanced bot protection from imperva here: https://www.imperva.com/products/advanced-bot-protection-management/

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are one way to do it. Another way would be to **import your user profile**. In this example I will assume you will be using *Chrome* as well as the *Selenium* library:

```
from selenium import webdriver


userdatadir = 'C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data' #path may be different for you
chromeOptions.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={userdatadir}")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)
driver.get("https://www.coches.net/segunda-mano/")
```

Essentially what this does is it **opens up a browser as if you were searching the web**.

Comment: After using selenium like 1 time it blocks me.